# tsx-Files (TypeScript JSX): Debugging?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

If I use tsx files (TypeScript JSX) in React, there are two transformations:

1. TypeScript
2. JSX

I guess it is not possible to debug this step by step since the JS interpreter does not know which lines in my tsx files get executed. But that's just a guess. Up to now, I am just reading about tsx.

Is it possible to debug this JavaScript code and see this debugging process in my (tsx) code?

Background: I want to learn react. Up to now, I developed Python for 20 years. I know some JavaScript and jquery.

(if you have hints on how to develop and debug tsx, please leave a comment)

Comment: It depends on your setup. Both typescript and babel (usually what is used for the react transform) support source maps. If you create the application with the react command line tool it should have builtin support for source maps and it should allow step by step debugging.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  if you write your comment as answer, then I can up-vote and accept it. Maybe some details how to set this up would be nice. Links to docs are enough for me. Thank you.

Comment: I put it as a comment because I don't know the ins and outs of how this works in react .. all I can say is create your aplication with https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app and it should "just work" If it does not, I don't really have a clue. Or if you have an app already setup I would not venture an answer on how to enable source maps with tsx in babel

Answer (score 0):

yes, yes it is. A big mistake a lot of people make (I myself was guilty of this) is not using strict, alwaysStrict, and strictNullChecks in their `tsconfig.json` files. Why? Strict Null Checking + alwaysStrict drastically enhances the usefulness of your typescript intellisense. Without these flags, it doesn't pick up on subtle errors which may have the potential to snowball into something highly undesirable

the other flag you can set in your tsconfig is the `jsx` option

set the flag to `"jsx": "preserve"`

Why?

this forces tsx to compile into jsx before being compiled down to js. This effectively creates an additional compilation layer, an activated ephemeral complex, like a stepwise reaction in chemistry

Contents of a tsconfig.json file I used on a recent nextjs project

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
            "@/config/*": ["config/*"],
            "@/graphql/*": ["graphql/*"],
            "@/lib/*": ["lib/*"],
            "@/pages/*": ["pages/*"],
            "@/scripts/*": ["scripts/*"],
            "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"],
            "@/test/*": ["test/*"],
            "@/types/*": ["types/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["**/*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out"]
}
```